# Jenkins cannot find the external Jars added for the selenium project through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have a Maven project in Eclipse. My project is for Automation Testing. So in my pom.xml I've all dependencies added.

For example: Testng, Cucumber, Selenium-java etc..

I have installed Jenkins and configured my automation project with Jenkins, so that when executed with Jenkins this project will be executed.

I have all dependencies added to my pom.xml so no issues was there. But now when I added the jar files externally in Eclipse, it is not recognized by Jenkins and therefore, script is not executed.

Here is my test case:

```
package com.giveback360.tests.sampletest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.giveback360.utils.OpenBrowserHelp;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import atu.testrecorder.ATUTestRecorder;
import atu.testrecorder.exceptions.ATUTestRecorderException;

public class SampleTest {

/**
* Initialize the webdriver.
*/
 private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

/**
 * Initialize recorder.
 */
 ATUTestRecorder recorder;

 /**
 * Open browser.
 * @throws InterruptedException the InterruptedException.
 */
 @When("Open browser maximize")
  public void browserOpen() throws InterruptedException, ATUTestRecorderException {

 recorder = new ATUTestRecorder("/home/username/workspace/project/scriptVideos","TestVideo",false);
 recorder.start();

 driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 Thread.sleep(4000);
 driver.quit();

 recorder.stop();

 }

}
```

My Console output in Jenkins is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: atu/testrecorder/exceptions/ATUTestRecorderException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: atu.testrecorder.exceptions.ATUTestRecorderException


Results :

Failed tests: 
 SampleTest>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass:16 » NoClassDefFound atu/tes...

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

The issue is because of ATUTestRecorder jar files I've added in Eclipse for this project.

Problem is how to instruct Jenkins to find those JAR files? Should I configure it in Jenkins or How should I do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 3rd party libraries in `lib` folder of your project.Then add them to maven with `<scope>system</scope>`

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mylib.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have set up a jar only with the eclipse build path so it only accessible for eclipse

while with the Jenkins you only setup a maven project so Jenkins is trying to find it's required dependency from POM.xml. it is not able to find the jar that is from eclipse build path.

You have to find maven declaration of that particular jar and have to put in POM.XML

or you can add 3rd party jar in maven using the following command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

[Find more information about adding 3rd party jar from here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)