# Jenkins job throws error when running Selenium WebDriver code. Running fine with Eclipse

Tags: java, git, maven, selenium, jenkins

Sorry for the lengthy post. Just wanted to be thorough.

This is my first attempt to build an automation testing framework including all the tools that are mentioned in the tags.
I figured out all the tools more or less (I get Passes). My issue is Maven configuration.

Created a test Maven project (open a webpage) in Eclipse and pushed it to GitHub. Created a job in Jenkins to install-test it with the use of a pom file.

When I run the pom.xml from Eclipse (right-click on file and use Run As) it works fine, test gets a Pass in the Console output.

When I run the Jenkins job I get the error below:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Jenkins/workspace/nwi navigation test/lbd/src/main/java/el/qa/sample/Navigation.java:[3,34] package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Jenkins/workspace/nwi navigation test/lbd/src/main/java/el/qa/sample/Navigation.java:[4,34] package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Jenkins/workspace/nwi navigation test/lbd/src/main/java/el/qa/sample/Navigation.java:[6,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Jenkins/workspace/nwi navigation test/lbd/src/main/java/el/qa/sample/Navigation.java:[7,38] package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Jenkins/workspace/nwi navigation test/lbd/src/main/java/el/qa/sample/Navigation.java:[11,24] cannot find symbol
```

Below are the lines from my pom.xml that I think should take care of it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

This is the line that Jenkins is executing (from console output):

```
[nwi navigation test] $ cmd.exe /C "mvn -f lbd\pom.xml install clean test && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
```

I have tried following this suggestion

> [Jenkins cannot find the external Jars added for the selenium project through Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082310/jenkins-cannot-find-the-external-jars-added-for-the-selenium-project-through-ecl)

```
<scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/selenium-java-3.8.1/client-combined-3.8.1.jar</systemPath>
```

and

```
 <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar</systemPath>
```

(replaced scope test with scope system) but nothing changed.

I will greatly appreciate your feedback on what am I missing!

Comment: I suspect the jenkins failed to download all dependency in pom file,  could you check jenkins job console output to see any error/failure message during jenkins downaload dependency stage or you supply the whole job console output.  If downaload dependency  fail, you need to supply a maven settings.xml same as your local to jenkins job.

Comment: Thank you yong! I will keep looking into it.